# Changing the background color with a variable in rshiny

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I'm trying to create a box in rshiny, which will have the background color set by the input variable. I've created an output:

```
 mainPanel(
      tags$div(uiOutput("image", align = "right"), h2(textOutput("text")), 
               div(textOutput("text2"),div(style = "width: 5px;"), "w",div(style = "width: 5px;"), textOutput("text3"), style = "display: flex"),
               div("tel. ", div(style = "width: 5px;"), textOutput("num"), style = "display: flex"),
               div("e-mail: ", div(style = "width: 5px;"), textOutput("text4"), style = "display: flex"),
               style= "width: 800px; height: 400px;color: black; font-size:15px;
               border: 5px solid white; padding: 15px; margin: 20px", class = "test")
    )
```

And now I'd like to modify the background color with a input by this:

```
eventReactive(input$kolor, {
    if(input$kolor == 1)
    {
      HTML('<style type="text/css">
        .test { background-color: white; }
        </style>')
      
    }
    else if(input$kolor == 2)
    {
      HTML('<style type="text/css">
        .test { background-color: green; }
        </style>')
    }
    else if(input$kolor == 3)
    {
      HTML('<style type="text/css">
        .test { background-color: blue; }
        </style>')
    }
  })
```

Unforunately, when I change the input variable - nothing happens. Any tips how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `renderUI` to achive this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
                sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
                  selectInput(
                    inputId = "color",
                    label = "Color",
                    choices = c("white", "green", "blue")
                  )
                ),
                mainPanel(uiOutput("mydiv"))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mydiv <- renderUI({
    div(
      "background-color test",
      width = "100px",
      height = "100px",
      style = sprintf("background-color:%s;", input$color)
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Or we can use `shinyjs::runjs`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(
      inputId = "kolor",
      label = "color",
      choices = setNames(c("white", "green", "blue"), 1:3)
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tags$div(uiOutput("image", align = "right"), h2(textOutput("text")), 
             div(textOutput("text2"),div(style = "width: 5px;"), "w",div(style = "width: 5px;"), textOutput("text3"), style = "display: flex"),
             div("tel. ", div(style = "width: 5px;"), textOutput("num"), style = "display: flex"),
             div("e-mail: ", div(style = "width: 5px;"), textOutput("text4"), style = "display: flex"),
             style= "width: 800px; height: 400px;color: black; font-size:15px;
               border: 5px solid white; padding: 15px; margin: 20px", class = "test", id = "testid")
  )
)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$kolor, {
    runjs(sprintf("document.getElementById('testid').style.backgroundColor = '%s';", input$kolor))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Okay, now it works! Missed the edit earlier. Thanks a lot :D